# Ethereum Sidechains can run it own smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, sidechain

When I use a sidechain to store certain information, are smart contracts made in Ethereum's main blockchain or can I have smart contracts inside my sidechain not using Ethereum main chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically side chain will have it own smart contract

Comment: But this contract will run on Ethereum main chain or in the sidechain? I'm asking that because of the fees to manipulate smart contracts in ethereum blockchain.

Comment: If you deploy the smart contract on the side chain then it on the side chain